# Enviando email (outlook) com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, email, outlook

Encontrei um código que faz o outlook abrir, mas quando o insiro no meu código ele não funciona.

ABAIXO O CODIGO QUE EU ENCONTREI

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mailBody"><table border=1> <tr><td>blabla</td></tr> </table></div>
<input type="tex" name="email" id="email">
<input type="tex" name="email2" id="email2">
<textarea name="teste"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="SendEmail();">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendEmail(){
    var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
    var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
    mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
    mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
    mailItem.Subject = "Me";
    mailItem.To = email.value + ";" + email2.value;
    mailItem.HTMLBody = teste.value;
    mailItem.display(0);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

AGORA O MEU CODIGO

```
<textarea name="textarea1" id="textarea1" rows="5" cols="40" id="salvar"></textarea>
        <input name="save" type="button" value="ADD CONTEINER"
           onclick="saveValues(); return false"/>
        &#0160;
        <input type="button" value="Enviar e-mail (outlook)" onclick="SendEmail(); return false">

function SendEmail(){
        var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
        var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
        mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
        mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
        mailItem.Subject = "Novo pedido";
        mailItem.To = email_pag1.value;
        mailItem.HTMLBody = textarea1.value;
        mailItem.display(0);
    }
```

Não entendo porque não ta funcionando!

Comment: Cara, utiliza a formatação pra código.
No editor tem a opção {}, você seleciona ela e colocar o seu código dentro

Comment: O seu código está dentro das *tags* `script` ou estão perdidas dentro do HTML como postou aqui?

Comment: Estão dentro das tag script

Comment: Já encontrei o erro.
Tem que formatar assim cada linha:

mailItem.HTMLBody = document.getElementById('textarea1').value;